# jquery live event for added dom elements

Tags: jquery, events, live

I want to add a class to any DOM element that is on the page now or in the future that has a specified class and meets some criteria

so for some pseudo code

```
$('.location').live('load',function(){
    if($(this).find('input:first').val().substr(0,1) == "!"){ $(this).addClass('hidden')}
});
```

of course this does nothing

**EDIT NOTE**

this does not work either

```
$('.location').live('load',function(){
    alert('adding location');
});
```

Comment: See my answer about using livequery() instead of live().  It's a plugin that live() was based on.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Do you have control over the code that is adding the elements to the page?

Comment: yes I do but was thinking it would be better to do it all in once place rather then modify all the different things that add items with that class

Answer (score 24, accepted):

jQuery's live() feature is just subset of the livequery plugin, which is much richer.  If you use livequery you could do something like..

```
$('.location').livequery(function() {
   // perform selector on $(this) to apply class   
});
```

That will cover existing elements plus any future elements added to the DOM.

Comment: so this is a plugin that needs to be included ?

Comment: +1 Didn't see this answer when I answered. Deleted mine. :o) Although I don't think I'd say that one is a subset of the other. The way they work is completely different.

Comment: @patrick.  Maybe subset is the wrong word.  What I mean is livequery() existed before jQuery added it's own live() feature.  And by subset I mean that the livequery plugin seems to be more robust (less about specific events) since you don't have to apply livequery to click,hover,change, etc.

Comment: @Gregg - Yes, in terms of the ultimate effect, `live()` would seem to be a feature subset of `livequery()`. But in fact `live()` doesn't actually do anything `livequery()` does. It just appears that way on the surface. :o)

Comment: You shouldn't need to use livequery if you upgrade the version of jQuery that you are using. This will save an extra download on each page.

Comment: @Daniel Dyson could you tell me how to do it without using livequery ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.

You'll have to do:

```
$('.location').filter(function () {
    return ($(this).find('input:first').val().substr(0, 1) == "!");
}).addClass('hidden');
```

To apply it to all currently elements on the page, and then manually add the 'hidden' class to future elements you add to the DOM.

Comment: hoping I can find something that will cover them all but this may be the only way

Comment: @Gregg: If you know a correct solution to add classes automatically to select elements that are added to the DOM at a later stage, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

The code `.subtr(0,1) = "!"` likely doesn't do what you want.

Comment: yes it does checking to see if the first character in the string is "!" I can't event get the alert me

Comment: There is a single `=` character there.

Comment: yes sorry my bad i had a typo you are correct but this is not the answer to the problem thanks for your help