# Using the Live method to bind a function to dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I bind the following to all future instances of checkboxes that might be added to my page dynamically. I'm not sure how to use the Live() method to do this.

```
        $('input:checkbox').imageTickBox({
            tickedImage: "/Content/Img/checkbox_tick.png",
            unTickedImage: "/Content/Img/checkbox_notick.png",
            imageClass: "tickbox"
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) (or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)). Those are for binding event handlers for events which may not yet exist.

> ***Description:** Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.*

The image tick box plugin you're using is not any sort of "event." You will have to explicitly call the initialization code (e.g. `$('selector').imageTickBox(...)`) whenever a new checkbox is added.

Comment: This is not true. Live will bind to new elements placed in to the DOM. Hence, the "_now and in the future_" in the Description you quoted.

Comment: And which event, pray tell, does the `imageTickBox` plugin use to style checkboxes? Live does not solve all problems. It is only useful for binding **event** handlers.

Comment: Ah, I see, I see. I misinterpreted the question. This is correct, but still ... you should be able to monitor the 'load' event when the element is loaded in to the DOM and then call the #imageTickBox method, no?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a duplicate question: Please see

[jquery live event for added dom elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840149/jquery-live-event-for-added-dom-elements)

[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/jquery-event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

`.live()` is for listening to events and then detecting where those events originated from. Adding elements to the page doesn't trigger anything that `.live()` can listen to. You'll have to call your plug-in initialization whenever you are adding the checkbox to the page.