# How to apply a function as soon as an element appears in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I know in jQuery that there's the function live() to suscribe to events as soon as an element appears. I just want to do something to an element as soon as it appears. I tried suscribing the elements to the "load" event but it doesn't work. How do you go about that?

Comment: See this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840149/jquery-live-event-for-added-dom-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the code which creates and appends elements, you could [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) a custom event and handle it in a handler later.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yG9ev/)

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    $('#container').append($('<div>Hello! I am a new div</div>')).trigger('div-added');
});

$('#container').bind('div-added', function() {
    alert('A div has been added');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't use load to all elements . only : Img Body Iframe.

and you can't listen via live to the load event of elements other  the ones i mentioned.

what you can do - is when you add them to the Page - Then you know when its happened and then you can call your func.

Answer (score 0):

Use .delegate() http://api.jquery.com/delegate instead of .live()

For your specific case consider livequery http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `DOMNodeInserted`.  I know that works in Webkit and Firefox - I don't know about IE though.

It would look something like this:

```
$('body').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(evt) {
    var addedElement = evt.target;
    // do whatever with `addedElement`...
})
```

Comment: `DOMNodeInserted` and other DOM mutation events have been deprecated in DOM 3. See http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents.