# Monitoring el changes in Backbone views?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

Say I have a Backbone view and I'm regularly replacing the content of el, how would I re-run non-event actions on the new adjusted el contents? For example; say I've replaced the contents and want to have all links use a lightbox script. To attach the script normally, you'd do something like this in render;

```
this.$el.find('a').box()
```

But after the content replacement, that would need to be run again. Given that you don't necessarily know when the el contents are being replaced, how would you re-run that? I can't seem to find an event I can delegate to for that--ready, load and change all sound like they could work, but none do. Ideally, I'd like something that I can put in the events hash to call a method which runs those things after each replacement.

Comment: Does the code that does the replacing always come from the same place?

Comment: There are several different components capable of replacing the content, so I need to figure out a sufficiently decoupled method of trigger some sort of "change" event to tell it to rerun any plugins it uses.

Comment: Is the content itself a view, or part of a view?

Comment: Kind of the point of the backbone view I thought was to encapsulate this very concept - if you want to change the content of the el then you should be doing it within the view and calling render() when you're done to re-render the widget. Otherwise what's the point of encapsulation on the view if you're changing the contents of the el in other places?

Comment: Normally I'd agree, but it's a whole bunch of tiny parts that aren't really big enough to warrant an entire view. I'd end up with another 15+ views and a codebase about 20-30x larger.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in your initialize:

```
$(this.el).livequery(function() {
   // perform selector on $(this) to apply box
});
```

Shamelessly stolen and slightly modified from [jquery live event for added dom elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840149/jquery-live-event-for-added-dom-elements)

Comment: Eww...I don't want to put in an entire third-party library for this. For now I'm just manually triggering a change event on the container everywhere that a content change is made from. Kind of hacky, but at least it keeps the event definitions standard and doesn't require relying on some third-party library--especially considering it hasn't been updated in 2 years!

Comment: Plus it's based on livequery, which is just like jQuery `live`, which will be deprecated because of its evilness.

Comment: OK fair enough.  I would add that if your backbone view isn't based on a model (which i assumed due to the change event not working) then there isn't really much that you're getting out of backbone views.  It's really only a convetion (see first paragraph of http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View)