# Best practice for when element is visible on the screen?

Tags: angularjs

In angular, I want to trigger a function and/or set a css-class once an element is actually visible on the screen, as in once you scroll down for example. What's the best practice for this?

Comment: Track the event that controls the visibility of the element: Mouse clicks, Key presses, HTTPs, etc

Comment: By visible, do you mean with a route, a `ng-if`, a `ng-show`.  Please give an example, thanks.

Comment: visible like visible on the screen, like if you scroll down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery event - element become visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584096/jquery-event-element-become-visible)

Comment: @Stewie, that is jquery?

Comment: More precisely, the question provides link to a [jquery.appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear) plugin, which will do all the "visibility detection" work for you. You just need to put it in a directive and act accordingly.

Comment: You may also check this [Check if element is visible after scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was trying to do the same thing and after lot of research I found a directive that does exactly what I needed:

https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview

It was also very easy to setup. In case you run into issues with this then let me know and I can help you out.